# create an image from the DOM using Web Workers

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, html2canvas, screen-capture

i am trying to build a screen capture feature but without any extensions,

so what i tried to do is to create an image from the Dom and send it using a web-socket.
this works, the problem is that the image creation process is slow and make all the ui stack(i am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)).

so i thought to use a web worker in order to do the processing on a different thread, the thread cant access the DOM and sending the DOM also doesn't do the trick as it does't send the original object only a shallow copy.

any one knows a way how it can be done. or should i need to change my approach? (using webrtc is not an option)

Comment: How is composed your page? How big is it? Would it be possible for you to split it in smaller parts, and call h2c in an timed-out loop?

Comment: @Kaiido its big. and its built on angler 6. i also tried to pass the html and print it in an iframe but that did a lot of mess and all the components  are lazy loaded . and h2t called inside setinterval every 500 mili

Comment: @AmitWagner I've faced with the same problem(. Have you managed to resolve it?

Comment: @IvanKovbas no. I send the dom part I want to send as a string and then render it on the other side

Comment: @AmitWagner passing as string and rendering with webworker work for you?

Comment: @libby not with web worker,